# How to sync files stored in git-annex with and from gitlab.com

Tags: git, gitlab, git-annex

I am trying to use `git-annex` with Gitlab.com but am getting an error when trying to sync my annexed files:

> git annex sync --content

```
(merging origin/git-annex into git-annex...)
(recording state in git...)
GitLab: API is not accessible

  Remote origin does not have git-annex installed; setting annex-ignore

  This could be a problem with the git-annex installation on the remote. Please make sure that git-annex-shell is available in PATH when you ssh into the remote. Once you have fixed the git-annex installation, run: git config remote.origin.annex-ignore false
commit  (recording state in git...)
ok
pull origin 
ok
pull origin 
ok
push origin
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

I am using the latest version of git annex (5/08/2015).

Comment: Are you connecting to your remote over SSH or HTTPS? https://about.gitlab.com/2015/02/17/gitlab-annex-solves-the-problem-of-versioning-large-binaries-with-git/

Comment: I should be using SSH, atleast `git remote -v` lists things starting with `git@`